# Почему получаю undefined через Апи ? В чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript, typescript

я получаю некие данные через АПИ, пример:

```js
{
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/p1F51Lvj3sMopG948F5HsBbl43C.j
  "belongs_to_collection": {
    "id": 131296,
    "name": "Thor Collection",
    "poster_path": "/yw7gr7DhHHVTLlO8Se8uH17TDMA.j
    "backdrop_path": "/3KL8UNKFWgIKXzLHjwY0uwgjzYl
  },
  "budget": 250000000,
  "genres": [
    { "id": 28, "name": "Action" },
    { "id": 12, "name": "Adventure" },
    { "id": 14, "name": "Fantasy" }
  ],
  "homepage": "https://www.marvel.com/movies/thor-
  "id": 616037,
  "imdb_id": "tt10648342",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Thor: Love and Thunder",
  "overview": "After his retirement is interrupted
  "popularity": 10909.273,
  "poster_path": "/pIkRyD18kl4FhoCNQuWxWu5cBLM.jpg
  "production_companies": [
    {
      "id": 420,
      "logo_path": "/hUzeosd33nzE5MCNsZxCGEKTXaQ.p
      "name": "Marvel Studios",
      "origin_country": "US"
    },
    {
      "id": 176762,
      "logo_path": null,
      "name": "Kevin Feige Productions",
      "origin_country": "US"
    }
  ],
  "production_countries": [
    { "iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States o
  ],
  "release_date": "2022-07-06",
  "revenue": 698864051,
  "runtime": 119,
  "spoken_languages": [
    { "english_name": "English", "iso_639_1": "en"
  ],
  "status": "Released",
  "tagline": "The one is not the only.",
  "title": "Thor: Love and Thunder",
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 6.768,
  "vote_count": 1740
}
```

Далее я прописываю интерфейс к этим данным:

```js
export interface MovieInfo 
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  belongs_to_collection: Be
  budget: number;
  genres: Genres[];
  homepage: string;
  id: number;
  imdb_id: string;
  orignal_language: string;
  original_title: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: number;
  poster_path: string;
  production_companies: Pro
  production_countries: Pro
  release_date: string;
  revenue: number;
  runtime: number;
  spoken_languages: SpokenL
  status: string;
  tagline: string;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
  vote_average: number;
  vote_count: number;
}
interface BelToCol {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  poster_path: string;
  backdrop_path: string;
}
interface Genres {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
interface ProdCompany {
  id: number;
  logo_path: string;
  name: string;
  origin_country: string;
}
interface ProdCountries {
  iso_3166_1: string;
  name: string;
}
interface SpokenLan {
  english_name: string;
  iso_639_1: string;
  name: string;
}
```

И в своем реакт компоненте уже получаю undefined по моему запросу, мой реакт компонент:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Movie.scss";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { MovieInfo } from "../../dataTypes";

export default function Movie() {
  const [currentMovieDetail, setMovieDetail] = React.useState<MovieInfo[]>([]);
  const { id } = useParams();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/616037?api_key=4e44d9029b1270a757cddc766a1bcb63&language=en-US`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setMovieDetail(data.results));
    console.log(currentMovieDetail);
  };
  return <div className="movie"></div>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Потому что сначала выполнится console.log, а только затем колбеки внутри then почитайте про асинхронность

Comment: Это да но ошибка все-равно не в этом, я даже без консоли не получаю данные

Comment: Скорей всего ошибка в типизации, const [currentMovieDetail, setMovieDetail] = React.useState<MovieInfo[]>([]); Но как исправить, пока не понимаю

Comment: Как вы понимаете, что не получаете данные? Возможно у объекта который вы получаете через get запрос нет свойства result

Comment: Да, вы правы, копипастнул с другого компонента result, данные все-же приходят но проблема все-равно вылазит. <h1>{currentMovieDetail.name}</h1> "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'MovieInfo[]'"

Comment: это уже видимо типы